# override settings in ApplicationHost.config file from my MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-7.5

I am working on an MVC application and I need to limit the number of concurrent users accessing the application to 20. 
I think so, I can do it using IIS settings. So my requirement is to override the ApplicationHost.Config file form the web.config of my MVC application. 
But I cannot find a way of doing it.

Comment: "I need to limit the number of concurrent users accessing the application to 20"...why? Is your server so under-powered? This seems like a very anti-user feature designed to annoy the ones who get locked out for no apparent reason from time to time. I'd love to know the business case for such a regressive requirement. Really you should just scale your system to meet the demand, surely?

Comment: My requirement is Licensing ! I need to limit the users based on the number of licenses purchased. So, if 20 licenses are purchased than the limit would be 20. That's how my client wants it.

Comment: Perhaps you should store in the database the last time a user logged in, and whether they have logged out or not since then. Combine that with how long a session can be active for, and you can work out how many users are currently logged on (or at least, have not logged out and therefore have an active session). Then when someone tries to log on you can check the number of currently active sessions, and require someone to log out (or their session time to have expired, if they don't manually log out) before anyone else can log in.

Comment: Because otherwise if you literally limit the number of concurrent _HTTP requests_ (not logged in users), which is what you seem to be proposing, you'll stop people from having more than one tab open, or making two requests concurrently (e.g. ajax), or logging on from more than one device, all of which are very common and expected scenarios in a modern web app. And also in your scenario, if the limit was reached, the 21st user would just think the site was down, since their connection would just be refused, and they'd be unaware the license limit was reached, and so might raise a support call

Comment: storing the sessions in a database is my second option. So, after the user logs in, I store the users data in a table. And after the user logs out, I should delete that entry from the table. So at any point of time I will come to know the number of concurrent users.
But the problem arises because we store the users ticket in a cookie and the expiration time is 30 mins. So after 30 mins, the users ticket expires and the users is auto logged out from the system. There is no event that tells me about this ticket expiry.

Comment: No there isn't, but if you record the time they last logged in, and the last time they made a request to the application, and check against the current time, you can work out whether their session has expired or not. You just have a little bit of logging overhead to record user activity.

Comment: Yes correct. So, should I write a windows service which runs every minute to check if the current time is ahead of the time the user last sent his last request by 30 minutes ? Is there any better option ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why you'd need a service to do anything. You only need to make such a check when someone new tries to log in. At that point you can use the latest log information to see how many people are currently logged in and also used the system within the last 30 minutes (i.e. so that their session has not expired)

Comment: wow ! thats even better. :) Thanks @ADyson